# Server was down for 4 hours. What will be the impact on SERPs?

Tags: search-results, migration, http-code-500

Yesterday, I was migrating my site to a new server. Due to a configuration error related to the zone file, my server was down for about 4 hours. (Server returned 500 error during this time.) My site ranks extremely well for hundreds of keywords and search-bots crawl thousands of pages every day (around 3000). Will the 4-hour downtime lead to a potential ranking drop in the near future?

P.S: So far rankings are good as usual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be no impact on your search engine rankings for an outage that lasts less than 24 hours.  Google understands that occasional outages are unavoidable.  They don't de-index pages or un-rank them just because of a single crawler error.  The next day Googlebot should retry requesting the any pages that had errors.  If it finds the pages then, your indexing and ranking won't have any problems.

It would be a good idea to watch your crawl reports in Google Search Console.   Google will likely report crawl errors from during this time.  You could help things along by triggering live inspections of pages where Googlebot found errors.

A grace period is the reason that Google treats "404 Not Found" errors differently than "410 Gone" errors.   404 errors can be caused by accidental deletion of files.   Google has said they give sites 24 hours to restore files before taking action based on a 404 error.   A "410 Gone" status almost always represents a deliberate removal of a page.  Google removes pages that return 410 status as soon as it can.

Outages lasting more than 24 hours can have a severe impact on SEO.   I had a site that was down for about a month.  It took rankings more than 6 months to recover after that.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether crawlers attempted to visit the site during that time.  If not, then "no one noticed" that your site was down.  Even if one crawler visited, others may not have.

So there is no way to tell whether or not there will be an impact.

Comment: Assuming crawlers encountered 500 errors, what could be the possible impact like?

Comment: There is no definite answer that. The impact will depend on what they see, how long they see it for and which search engine.  They may remove the site or they may not or they may check again later or they may not or they may do any of a number of things that we do or do not know about.